Error in connection querying MotifDb in R
I don't understand why some days ago this line was working
MotifDb [grep ('TWIST1', values (MotifDb)$geneSymbol, ignore.case=TRUE)]
Hsapiens_TWIST1 <- query(MotifDb, "TWIST1")

while now when I run it I get the error
> MotifDb [grep ('TWIST1', values (MotifDb)$geneSymbol, ignore.case=TRUE)]
MotifDb object of length 4
| Created from downloaded public sources, last update: 2022-Mar-04
| 4 position frequency matrices from 4 sources:
|         cisbp_1.02:    1
|         jaspar2018:    1
|         jaspar2022:    1
|       SwissRegulon:    1
| 1 organism/s
|           Hsapiens:    4
Hsapiens-cisbp_1.02-M6527_1.02 
Hsapiens-jaspar2018-TWIST1-MA1123.1 
Hsapiens-jaspar2022-TWIST1-MA1123.2 
Hsapiens-SwissRegulon-TWIST1.SwissRegulon 
> Hsapiens_TWIST1 <- query(MotifDb, "TWIST1") [[1]]  
Error in autosocket() : banknameSocket not found, try choosebank() first

If I get it correctly, this error is a connection problem to MotifDb. I load its library correctly enter code here
Nothing happend to the code. Two days ago worked correctly without errors, while now I'm stuck there.
